# SiteCatalyst: New vs Repeat visitors plugin query

Tags: web-analytics, web-analytics-tools, adobe-analytics

I am tracking visitors not by the cookies but by explicitly populating the
s.visitorID variable with unique visitor IDs on all pageviews.

Now, I want to get a New vs Repeat visitors report. I am aware of the
getNewRepeat plugin which works using cookies.

Is there any Plugin for new vs repeat visitor report for tracking done by
s.visitorID? If not, how can I get the New vs Repeat visitors report in a non-cookie based setup?

Please help with the same. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The getNewRepeat plugin creates a new cookie just to track that information. It will work with cookies or a custom visitorID because it is completely seperate (another cookie). If what you mean is that you aren't able or willing to use cookies at all, you will need a different mechanism to track whether a visitorID was just set (new visitor) or was already set (returning visitor) - emulating the way the plugin would normally work.

Comment: Thanks Nils. What I understand is: When user visits the first time, this plugin will set a cookie. So next time this visitor visits, the plugin can read the cookie and say that its a returning visitor. However, after the first visit, if the user 'deletes cookies' in browser, he will be classified as new user on 2nd visit. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: That's correct. Do you have a way to always give a visitor the same visitorID?

Comment: Yes. Because all pageviews will be behind a login. So on login, the visitorID matching to the userID will be passed.

Answer (score 0):

When a user logs in for the first time, set an eVar to 'New'. 
On subsequent logins, set the same eVar to 'Repeat'.

Comment: That is a good way to do it. But how do I identify in sitecatalyst whether it is first login for a user or subsequent login?

Comment: You would set the value in the eVar on the server side, when you provide the value for their visitorID.

Comment: Thanks Nils but Pardon me but I am quite new to SiteCatalyst. Can you please let me know as to how can I set the value in the eVar on the server side?

Comment: It depends on what language your server is running, but you could have something like this in the Omniture code block on the login page - `eVar1 = '<% Login type %>';`

Comment: Thanks Nils. I had one more query about custom link tracking on webkit browsers(E.g-Chrome). Can you please help me with the same?
Please refer to the query here:
http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/webanalytics/message/30100


Would be glad if you can help on this since have so far got no help on this from anywhere else.
Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,
Harshil

Comment: @harshilshah If my answer to your original question was correct or useful, accept it as the answer, and then post a new question about the link tracking issue. I can then give you the answer on that new post. Cheers

Comment: Hi Nils, I already accepted that solution in the comment at Apr 10 6:25. Also, thanks for the details on setting this variable server side. This would be lot helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Nils, posted the new post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355850/sitecatalyst-tracking-custom-links-on-webkit-browsers        please help on the same