# SiteCatalyst : Tracking Custom links on Webkit browsers

Tags: web-analytics, web-analytics-tools, adobe-analytics

My query is that I have a link that redirects to another page. In webkit browsers, how to force the sitecatalyst server call (script execution) to finish before the redirect happens?

I am using sitecatalyst for a portal. I have
configured the custom link call to include the doneAction parameter for
successful call completion on webkit browsers (As mentioned in Adobe guide).

The custom link code for onClick event of button is as below:

```
<script language="javascript" >
function search(keyword)
{
var s=s_gi('testing');
s.linkTrackVars="prop11,events";
s.linkTrackEvents="event6";
s.prop11=keyword;
s.events="event6";
s.tl(this,'o','Search',navigate());

window.location=searchresults.html;
}
</script>

<script language="javascript" >
function navigate()
{
return false;

/*To induce a delay to ensure that image request is sent to Adobe before the
user leaves the page.(As given in Adobe guide - code release H.25))
Code version H.25 (released July 2012) includes an overloaded
track link method ( s.tl ) that forces WebKit
browsers to wait for the track link call to complete.)*/
}
</script>
```

However, even after this, I am getting error in custom link tracking. The redirect happens before the call can complete.

Please help on the same. Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Harshil

Answer (score 5):

Okay so firstly there are a number of issues with how you implemented it. Here is an example of how it should look like:

```
<a href="searchresults.html" onclick="search('someKeyword');return false;">search</a> 

<script type='text/javascript'>
function search(keyword) {
  var s=s_gi('testing');
  s.linkTrackVars="prop11,events";
  s.linkTrackEvents="event6";
  s.prop11=keyword;
  s.events="event6";
  s.tl(this,'o','Search',null,navigate);
  return false;
}

function navigate(){
  window.location="searchresults.html";
}
</script>
```

Some points

- You didn't actually post the link or whatever you are using that calls the `search` function so I have a link shown as an example.
- You passed the `navigate` function as the 4th argument when it should be the 5th (with a null or blank string as a placeholder for the 4th)
- It should be `navigate` not `navigate()`. The way you did it, you are making a call to the function and passing the result of the function as an argument. `s.tl` requires the actual function or reference to a function, and it will make the call to the function. In fairness, the Adobe document is typoed: it shows the example wrapped in quotes which doesn't work.
- The redirect should be placed in `navigate`, not in `search`.

Comment: ..okay? was there a question or something you had?

Comment: Sorry. By mistake I posted this. I am trying out the changes suggested by you. Will let you know on the same as soon as I am done. Thanks so much for the response.

Comment: Crayon,

Thanks so much for hte much needed help. This now works!

Except for where, my s.tl() call is not within some event handler. In such a scenario, it is not working.
Following is the code of such a scenario: (Posted in multiple comments as it was over the allowable character limits)

Comment: function LogIn()
{
 var s=s_gi('testing');
 s.linkTrackVars="events";
 s.linkTrackEvents="event3";
 s.events="event3";
 s.tl(true,'o','Login Attempt');

 loggedin=false;
 username="";
 password="";
 username=prompt("Username:","");
 username=username.toLowerCase();
 password=prompt("Password:","");
 password=password.toLowerCase();
 if (password=="pwd")
 {
  loggedin=true;
  var s=s_gi('testing');
  s.linkTrackVars="eVar1,eVar5,events";
  s.linkTrackEvents="event4";
  s.eVar5="Login Success";
  s.events="event4";
  s.tl(this,'o','Login Success',null,navigate);
  return false;
 }

Comment: if (loggedin==false)
 {
  var s=s_gi('testing');
  s.linkTrackVars="events";
  s.linkTrackEvents="event5";
  s.events="event5";
  s.tl(true,'o','Login Failure');
  alert("Invalid login!");
 }
}

function navigate()
{
 var v1 = getQuerystring('referrer');
 if (v1==1)
 window.location="Page 9.html?referrer=1";
 else
 window.location="Home Page.html?ref=3";
}

Comment: In the above scenario, the redirect is triggered only if password=="pwd".
So, here I have made the changes in the s.tl() call accordingly.
However, 'Login Success' is not getting captured.

Please help on the same.

Best Regards,
Harshil

Answer (score 1):

Replace the link href with javascript function

```js
function trackLink(e) {
    nextUrl = e.href;
    e.href = "javascript:sendData('" + nextUrl + "')";
}

function sendData(url) {
    s.tl(this, "o", "Link Name", null, function() {
        window.location.href = url;
    });
}
```

or try out the following

```js
function sendData(obj) {
    s.tl(obj, "o", "Link Name", null, "navigate");
    return false;
}
```

```html
<a href="new.html" onclick="sendData(this);return false;">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Link tracking is a dinosaur form of tracking as the numbers are barely accurate these days if you are not putting analytics before user experience. What I don't understand is that why don't you measure this on the next page instead of the link, unless you have no control over the next step?

As for your question: Previous examples on how to prevent link following before event is executed are quite solid, but remember if you have other JS code binded, be sure not to break it. As for the syntax, you can pass all variables to s.tl function as an object without setting linkTrackVars and linkTrackEvents for the s-object, which might have negative effects on events if case you use the code on dynamic pages.

E.g.

```
...  
var data = {
   linkTrackVars="prop11,events",
   linkTrackEvents="event6",
   prop11=keyword,
   events="event6"
};
s.tl(this, "o", "Search", data, "navigate");
...
```

Note: You can't actually use props and events together in standard reporting. As per the code you pasted in comments to Crayon I can see that you are using eVars, so I assume that the example was not that accurate.

Comment: While in general i will agree that tracking link clicks that target other pages you already track is generally not something you should do, IMO if there is a legit need for it, tracking the click from the target landing page is also usually not a good idea. You have no way of knowing that the visitor landed on the target page by clicking on that link unless you have code in place that does not allow for a visitor to get to that page except by first clicking that specific link. Sites are rarely coded this way, except for on conversion pages or steps in a funnel (and even then many times the..

Comment: ..site isn't coded for that). Even if you were to put a url param to mark the link, it's still not a guarantee that the visitor arrived there by clicking that link on the original page vs. bookmarking and going directly or link was passed around or showed up in a serp etc.

Comment: This is why the data must be set on click, but read on the next step. URL parameters do not suit this need, but rather first party cookies or session storage methods. I agree that both on-click and next-page trackings have their weaknesses, but in my perspective its better to track links that worked than to track all the clicks of which we have no way of confirming how many we clicked, as per the unreliability of the method.